# Estou com este erro SQL Error [1215] [HY000]: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou usando o MySQL com o DBeaver, ao inserir o codigo no DBeaver o mesmo apresentou este erro:

> SQL Error [1215] [HY000]: Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Cliente:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
ID_CLIENTE integer PRIMARY KEY,
CPF integer,
NOME varchar(100),
IDADE integer,
DEBITOS numeric(4,2)
);
```

FEEDBACK:

```
CREATE TABLE FEEDBACK (
ID_CLIENTE integer,
ID_AVALIACAO integer,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_CLIENTE, ID_AVALIACAO)
);
```

Parte do código que erro aponta:

```
ALTER TABLE FEEDBACK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FEEDBACK_1
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTE)
REFERENCES CLIENTE (ID_CLIENTE)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Como eu arrumo este erro?

Comment: Algum id_client de feedback não existe em cliente.

Comment: `ON DELETE SET NULL`, por que precisa disso? Sendo ID_CLIENTE parte da sua chave primária, você iria ter NULL sendo indexado como PK? Tem certeza que é isso que gostaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema está sendo causado porque o seu comando `ALTER TABLE` possui uma inconsistência em sua declaração.
A inconsistência está em querer setar uma chave primária para o valor `NULL`.

No banco de dados `mysql` quando definimos uma coluna da tabela como uma `PRIMARY KEY`, estamos implicitamente declarando esta coluna como `UNIQUE` e `NOT NULL`.

Como cita a [`documentação`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), procure por `PRIMARY KEY` (terceira ocorrência)

> Um índice único onde todas as colunas-chave devem ser definidas
> como `NOT NULL`. Se eles não forem declarados explicitamente como `NOT NULL`, o MySQL os declara implicitamente (e silenciosamente). Uma tabela
> pode ter apenas uma `CHAVE PRIMÁRIA`. O nome de uma PRIMARY KEY é sempre
> PRIMARY, que portanto não pode ser usado como o nome para qualquer
> outro tipo de índice.

Dito isto, para resolver o problema basta modificar o comando `ALTER TABLE` para não ter a cláusula `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Desta forma o seu `ALTER TABLE` ficaria assim:

```
ALTER TABLE FEEDBACK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FEEDBACK_1
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTE)
REFERENCES CLIENTE (ID_CLIENTE);
```